# Is it possible to deserialize inline arrays with Json.NET?

Tags: json.net

Let me try to simplify my question by extracting and abstracting relevant information from a complex object and large JSON text.

```
Class Foo()
{
  string Name;
  Version[] versions;
}
```

JsonText(converted from XML) can be something like this:

```
  "Foo": {
    "Name": "test",
    "versions": {
        "Major": "1",
        "Minor": "1"
    },
    "versions": {
        "Major": "2",
        "Minor": "1"
    },
    "versions": {
        "Major": "3",
        "Minor": "1"
    }
    }
```

or the following:

```
  "Foo": {
    "Name": "test",
    "versions": {
        "Major": "1",
        "Minor": "1"
    }
    }
```

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonText) results in:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Version[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

Is it possible to do this desrialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated based on commment**

Your Json doesn't look valid. A Json needs to be enclosed with "[" "]". For example,

```
[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
```

If you are allowed to modify your Json, You could modify the Json as following

```
{
"Foo": 
{
    "Name": "test",
    "versions": [
    {
        "Major": "1",
        "Minor": "1"
    },
    {
        "Major": "2",
        "Minor": "1"
    },
    {
        "Major": "3",
        "Minor": "1"
    }]
}
}
```

Based on your comment, you would like to avoid the Json Array Syntax if there is only a single element. On other cases, you would like to stick to Array Syntax. In such scenario,you could write a Custom Json Converter.

```
class CustomConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<T>>().ToArray();
        }
        return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() }.ToArray();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can decorate your class with **JsonConverter** attribute to use the Custom Json Converter.

```
class Wrapper
{
    public Foo Foo{get;set;}
}
class Foo
{
  [JsonProperty("Name")]
  public string Name{get;set;}

  [JsonProperty("versions")]
  [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter<Version>))]
  public Version[] versions{get;set;}
}
```

Now you can deserialize as

```
var result =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(str);
```

This would now work, if you use either of following Json definition.

```
 {
    'Foo': 
    {
        'Name': 'test',
        'versions': [
        {
            'Major': '1',
            'Minor': '1'
        },
        {
            'Major': '2',
            'Minor': '1'
        },
        {
            'Major': '3',
            'Minor': '1'
        }]
    }
    }
```

Single Version (Without Array syntax)

```
  {
    'Foo': 
    {
        'Name': 'test',
        'versions': 
        {
            'Major': '1',
            'Minor': '1'
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for lending a hand.   I should have given a bit more background about the question.  I will try later.  I take your answer as "no" to my question given the Json text in my post.  The Json is converted from an Xml file. I will accept your answer if I do not see a better one.

Comment: I edited my question, and added a case with valid Json.  The error is the same.  Based on you answer, I guess that I need to add [] even when there is only one  element in the array.

Comment: @Hong I do not understand. So you want to create a Json structure, where if there is only one element, you need to use without Json Array and if more, you want to use Json Array ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I cannot change the class.  versions is always an array. I cannot deserialize it with Json.NET no matter whether there is only one element or many elements due to the mentioned error.  Changing Json text is theoretically possible in this case, but a bit challenging in reality.  The real situation is there lots of complex classes with this situation.

Comment: @Hong I have updated my answer to support Single Element/Array. Could you please check if thats what you meant ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant if I understand it correctly.   It is late night here.  I will try it tomorrow and report back.  Actually hundreds of of complex classes are auto-generated, and auto-updated periodically, so I will have to figure out a way to add the attribute automatically. Hand-coding is not an option.

Comment:  Works both on PC and iPad.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you are apparently an expert in Json.NET, i'd like ask a  somewhat related question.  I do not a have a single JsonProperty like [JsonProperty("Name")] in the class c# file, but the deserialization works beautifully.  I assume this has to do with the naming of the properties.  Their names match the names in Json, so there is no need for JsonProperty attribute. Right?